# Reading String in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a function that reads from a String in Haskell, if the String has a number, it should return True.
This is what I currently have

```
hasNumber :: String -> Bool
hasNumber n = any number
```

I have tried lots of functions in the second line but it doesn't seem to work, can anyone help me? 
Thank you!

Comment: Well, obviously you need to insert a 'real' function for number (I think you mean "digit" here?). What have you tried for that?

Comment: Where you trying to use `number :: Integral i => Int -> GenParser tok st Char -> GenParser tok st i` from `Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Number`, or what's that `number` in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to check whether your string is an natural number it boils down to

```
import Data.Char (isDigit)

hasNumber :: String -> Bool
hasNumber = all isDigit
```

If you don't want to use `Data.Char` (or aren't allowed if this is an assignment), you can use

```
isDigit = (`elem` ['0'..'9'])
```

If you want to check whether the number is integral, you have to check whether the string starts with a '-', and if it does, whether the rest of the string is a natural number:

```
isIntegral :: String -> Bool
isIntegral ('-':[]) = False        -- string is "-", which isn't a number
isIntegral ('-':xs) = hasNumber xs -- string is "-....", so we check "...."
isIntegral x        = hasNumber x  -- string doesn't start with '-'
```

Comment: `hasNumber "-37" == False`. Maybe you meant natural number, not integral number?

Comment: @kqr: Yes. Added `isIntegral` for completion.

Answer (score 2):

Should refine what you want by "number", but supposing you want to simply read one of the Haksell numeric types formatted as a string in the way Haskell prints them, then you can use the `readMaybe` function.

```
import Text.Read

hasNumber :: String -> Bool
hasNumber x = isJust ( readMaybe x :: Maybe Int )
```

If you want to read a different numeric type than change the type annotation to `Maybe Double`, `Maybe Integer` or whatever you want.

If you need to parse a variety of number formats that differ from the way that Haskell `show`s them by default, then use a parser library like Parsec.